# The Postgres base container on Windows crashes

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

Usually I work on Linux and I created this project there also but I have a need to run it on Windows and when I run it my database crashes

```
   2023-10-03 09:35:35.818 UTC [83] FATAL:  data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" has invalid permissions 
   2023-10-03 09:35:35.818 UTC [83] DETAIL:  Permissions should be u=rwx (0700) or u=rwx,g=rx (0750). 
   child process exited with exit code 1 
   initdb: removing contents of data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data"
   running bootstrap script ...
```

on startup i get this error from the base container while the dockerfile and dockerfile compose look like this

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
```

and

```
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_NAME=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Maybe someone has encountered this and knows what to do in such a case?

Comment: You need to make the host `./data/db` directory permissions match what's in the error message.  Using a named volume instead of a host directory here also might help.